# Tooltip background-color wrong in FF

Tags: firefox, primefaces

I use a `<p:tooltip>` element and have a CSS entry which looks like this

```
.ui-tooltip {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Astounishingly, it is displayed correctly in IE9, but there is **no background-color in FF 27**.

All classes of the tooltip are: `ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-shadow ui-corner-all`. If I use Firebug and manually add the attribute, it works. But the class ui-tooltip is found, so what happens here?

Comment: Have you tried setting `!important` ?

Comment: `!important` is a bad practice, maybe you should have a look on the order of the css files you have... basically your css file should be called after primefaces.css ...

Comment: tried `!important`, not working. I don't see any other css that sets a background-color. How can I see the order of css files?

Comment: just see the source, right click in your browser > view source.. look in the head tag

Comment: It is called after primefaces.css, almost in the end; only 1140styles.css comes after